# Change Add comment form but not Edit comment form, and vice-versa

Tags: 8, entities

I have a comment type named "reviews" (it happens to be a field in a node that's displayed alongside webform submissions).

I'm trying to differentiate between the *add* comment form and the *edit* comment form so I could, for example, alter the submit button text (value) on one but not the other.

I'm currently using **HOOK_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)**

In both cases (add and edit):

- `$form['form_id']['#id']` = `edit-comment-reviews-form`
- `$form['#id']` = `comment-form`
- `$form_state->getFormObject()->getOperation()` = `default`

Is there anything in `$form` I'm missing?

**Solution:**

```
$entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
if ($entity->isNew()) {
   ...
```

Comment: IMHO still a duplicate after the edit. If getOperation() is default see the other answer in the linked question.

Comment: @4k4 thanks - have since added that one that worked.